# Filter JSON data in TextField

Tags: django

Version that I use:

```
psycopg2==2.6.2
django=1.10.5
postgres=9.3
```

I want to store JSON data to the database using Django, but I can't use JSONField() because it needs `jsonb` type that only present in PostgreSQL >=9.4.

My Django model is as follows:

```
class Inspection(models.Model):
    data = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False)
```

In the `data` field I want to store JSON data.

The data is as follows:

**Record1:**

```
{
  "url": "some_url",
  "user": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "email": "myemail@hotmail.com",
      "first_name": "My_First_Name",
      "last_name": "My_Last_Name"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Record2**:

```
{
      "url": "some_url",
      "user": [
        {
          "id": "2",
          "email": "myemail_2@hotmail.com",
          "first_name": "My_First_Name_2",
          "last_name": "My_Last_Name_2"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Can I filter on `user id`?

Comment: Did you mean this [jsonfield](https://github.com/dmkoch/django-jsonfield)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
id = 1
Inspection.objects.filter(data__icontains='"id": "{}"'.format(id))
```

try with above and use space after colon (:) symbol.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement you own filter. Take a look at [this](https://www.dabapps.com/blog/higher-level-query-api-django-orm/) article. You can write SQL query directly, and put it in custom filter.